# How do I correctly code an abstract class and its subclasses to have getter/setter behavior?

Tags: python, abstract-class

In Python (3.11) I have this abstract class:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from copy import deepcopy

class BookPrototype(metaclass=ABCMeta):
  
    @property
    def title(self):
        pass

    @title.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def title(self, val):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def clone(self):
        pass
```

I create this subclass:

```
class ScienceFiction(BookPrototype):

    def title(self, val):
        print("this never gets called without decorator")

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def clone(self):
        return deepcopy(self)
```

And use it this way:

```
science1 = ScienceFiction()
science1.title = "From out of nowhere"
science2 = science1.clone()
print(science2.title)
science2.title = "New title"
print(science2.title)
print(science1.title)
```

This code does exactly what I want, that is it creates an instance of `ScienceFiction` class, it clones it, it prints the title of the cloned object and again the title of the first one. So, my prints here are "From out of nowhere", "New Title", "From out of nowhere".

Problem is when, following [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty), I add the `@BookPrototype.title.setter` decorator to the title setter, this way:

```
@BookPrototype.title.setter
    def title(self, val):
        print("this gets called now")
```

In this case the print inside the title method works, BUT I can't assign any value, so that the code prints three None.

What am doing wrong? How do I correctly code an abstract class and its subclasses to have getter/setter behavior?

Comment: the title value should be stored in a variable (e.g. `self._title`) . In your first version (without the decorator), your overload the function with a `str` variable

Comment: I suggest you check the third example in the property [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)

Comment: @RemiCuingnet I've done this before, I couldn't post any of my attempt  :-)  but it didn't work. Anytime I add the decorators, the code fails to work

Comment: @RemiCuingnet it works if I remove BookPrototype from the decorator. Now, I'm even more confused because I don't understand why the docs state I have to decorate it with the base class added. The craziest thing of all is in this case I can even remove the def title from the base class, and it still works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title value should be stored in a variable. For instance it could be stored in `self._title` in the base class.
I think what you are looking for is something like:
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from copy import deepcopy

```
class BookPrototype(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    def __init__(self):
        self._title: str = ""

    @property
    def title(self):
        return self._title

    @title.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def title(self, val):
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def clone(self):
        ...

class ScienceFiction(BookPrototype):
    @BookPrototype.title.setter
    def title(self, val):
        self._title = val

    def clone(self):
        return deepcopy(self)

science1 = ScienceFiction()
science1.title = "From out of nowhere"
science2 = science1.clone()
print(science2.title)
science2.title = "New title"
print(science2.title)
print(science1.title)

# From out of nowhere
# New title
# From out of nowhere
```

When you remove the decorator `@BookPrototype.title.setter` as in :

```
class ScienceFiction(BookPrototype):

    def title(self, val):
        print("this never gets called without decorator")

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def clone(self):
        return deepcopy(self)
```

setting the variable `title` with a string just override the method with a `str` object. This can be seen with the following :

```
science = ScienceFiction()
print(type(getattr(science, 'title')))
science.title = "From out of nowhere"
print(type(getattr(science, 'title')))

# <class 'method'>
# <class 'str'>
```

Note that in python you can dynamically add / modify / delete attributes.

Comment: I'm new to Python. My goal was to create an abstract class as it was an interface in other languages, that is without any implementation. Is this possible?

Comment: yes this is possible either as you did with `abstractmethod`. You can also set the property (the getter) as abstract and implement it (including the variable `self._title`)  in the derived class. Another approach if you are looking for an interface without the inheritance you can have a look to [protocols](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#defining-a-protocol).